# Is it possible to join two tables to classify an information without a common column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables as follows

Table 1

```
ServerName  Details1 Details2 Details3
--------------------------------------
xyzG01p0    blah     blah     blah
abczG02p0   blah     blah     blah
efgG01S01   blah     blah     blah
dfgG06P0    blah     blah     blah
```

Table 2

```
 Classification  Name
  ---------------------
  G01p0    G01
  G02p0   G02
  G01S01   G01S0
  G06P0    G06
```

I'm trying to find the classification from table2 which can be part of the servername from `table1`. Is that possible? I need to identify for example, xyzG01p0 as G01 based on two tables and need to perform some actions based on that!

Comment: As posted this doesn't make much sense. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to find the classification from table2 which can be part of the servername from table1? You might take a loook here for a great starting location. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: yes exactly.. I'm trying to find the classification from table2 which can be part of the servername from table1

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: @Tab Alleman Sorry! I am new to TSQL and only aware of joins with tables having common column. I'm here in a doubt whether that is even possible!

Comment: Research means searching the internet to learn the things you don't already know, and/or experimenting with attempts to code and finding out what does and doesn't work.   If you did either of those things before asking your question, you should include a description of that effort in your question.

Comment: @TabAlleman I'll keep that in mind in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

**[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/369231)**

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.ServerName LIKE '%' + t2.Classification
```

But it will have poor performance, because it is nonSARG-able

Comment: The query returns 0 result set to me!!

Comment: @Ramya First of all don't shout. Second see demo, if needed use `ON t1.ServerName LIKE '%' + t2.Classification + '%'`

Comment: Thank you very much @lad2025 ... It works now after i add % at the end.. I didn't mean to be rude .. Sorry!

Comment: @Ramya Great, but I don't see your data, and for snippet you give preceding '%' should work. For future please prepare http://sqlfiddle.com